Intermittent JAXBException Error in WebLogic - "isContentLengthReqd is not a valid property" During Restart
I'm encountering an issue while restarting my WebLogic server, and I need some guidance. Specifically, I'm getting the following error:
weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: isContentLengthReqd is not a valid property on class com.example.architecture.ecm.jaxws.DoSearch
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated.
Caused By: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: isContentLengthReqd is not a valid property on class com.example.architecture.ecm.jaxws.DoSearch
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:960)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBRIContextWrapper.java:120)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:599)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createArgumentsBuilder(TieHandler.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.<init>(TieHandler.java:115)
        Truncated.

Background:
The application is using WebLogic 12c.
This error occurs during the startup of the managed server during a restart.
The class com.example.architecture.ecm.jaxws.DoSearch is part of the web service.
The property isContentLengthReqd seems to be missing or incorrectly mapped in the JAXB context.
What I've tried:
Clearing the WebLogic cache: Stopped the server, cleared the cache, and restarted it.
The error message suggests that the JAXB context cannot find the property isContentLengthReqd on the DoSearch class. Could this be caused by an issue with the JAXB binding or the WSDL/XML schema?
My questions:
Has anyone encountered this issue where WebLogic is unable to map the JAXB property during startup? How did you resolve it?
Is there anything specific to WebLogic's handling of JAXB annotations that could be causing this?
Are there any additional debugging steps I can take to understand why the isContentLengthReqd property is being missed during startup?
for weblogic 12.2.1.4 we are using rhel 8 machine and java 1.8.0_431 versions
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
